# React.js Polymorphism: Checking Child Type Fails

Tags: reactjs

I've got a situation where I have a `NavGroup` with a `renderAs` prop with possible values of `Div`, `Collapsible` and `Dropdown` to achieve a sort of "Polymorphism" in React.js. It works well until I get down into the `Collapsible` or `Dropdown` and want to check children for a `CollapsibleHead` or `DropdownToggle` but only find `NavGroupHead`.

**See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bipahi/3/edit?html,js,output)**.

Since the `Dropdown` and `Collapsible` components can't find the child they are looking for the event handlers aren't being attached and I can't get no satisfaction.

I am in need of enlightenment: Am I on the right track? Is there a simple solution for this? Or am I thinking about this all wrong and should do something completely different? Is there a "React Way" for doing this sort of thing? What is it? If not, should there be?

Answer (score 0):

You're always seeing the same type of component where you've marked a TODO because your cloned child components are rendering themselves by returning another type of component - this doesn't replace the child component.

If you use the React Developer Tools, this is what you'll see for your Collapsible example:

```
<Collapible>
  <div>
    <NavGroupHead>
      <CollapsibleHead>
```

I think doing what you're trying to to (components which render themselves by rendering more specific components) nicely may depend on this change to React's currently-undocumented context feature:

- [Switch the Context to use the Parent tree instead of the Owner tree](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2112)
- See [Introduction to Contexts in React.js](http://www.tildedave.com/2014/11/15/introduction-to-contexts-in-react-js.html) in lieu of docs for now

Contexts are an alternative to manually passing props down the tree. In this case, one of your examples is a `Collapsible`, which wants to pass a callback down to the link which will be used to toggle collapsing.

Instead of having to clone each and every component on the way down to the link, a `Collapsible` could provide the callback using `getChildContext()` and a Collapsible-specific child component could later pick it up off `this.context` and generate a link with an `onClick` prop (or clone `NavLink` and change it use a JSX spread to pass all its props to the link it creates)

As it currently stands the context will be lost once rendering hits `<NavGroupHead>`, as this is owned by another component.

I encountered the same issue when trying to implement block-based template inheritance using context to hold stacks of blocks:

- [A failed attempt to implement block inheritance using React contexts](https://gist.github.com/insin/bcca5b64c6bcf95ad535)